# Is there a function with prescribed zeros and poles on an elliptic curve?

Tags: riemann-surfaces, elliptic-functions, meromorphic-functions

Let $T$ be the complex tore from the lattice $(1, \tau)$ where $im(\tau)>0$.

**How to prove the existence of a meromorphic function on $T$, with divisor $(0) + (\frac{1}{2}) - 2 (\frac{\tau}{2})$ ?** (i.e with simple zeros at 0 and $\frac{1}{2}$ and a double pole at $\frac{\tau}{2}$).

I have troubles using Riemann Roch for the question I ask because it gives the dimension of the space based on an inequality of divisors.

**Clue**

If it can help, the question above is the 2nd question of an exercise, the first one being: what are the holomorphic 1-forms on $T$?

My answer for this preliminary question: if $\omega$ is the Weirstrass invariant 1-form, then all 1-forms are $f.\omega$ with $f$ meromophic. $f$ must be of the form $g(\rho) + \rho'h(\rho)$ and since we don't want any poles this leaves only constants: all holomorphic 1-forms are $k \omega, k \in \mathbb{C}$. So $l(K)=1$ (from Riemann Roch)

But then I don't know how this helps for finding principal divisors of $(0) + (\frac{1}{2}) - 2 (\frac{\tau}{2})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A theorem says that if $x_i$ are the zeros or poles of a function with orders $n_i$, then $\sum n_i x_i \in \Lambda$ which is not the case here.